Registering A Custom Post Type/Taxonomy from Plugin
I see similar questions, but I think I am just too inexperienced to understand the solutions.
I am using the Agile Store Locator, which allows us to manage multiple locations. I want to somehow register the stores as a custom post type, or add a taxonomy that includes all the stores in the database. I have CPT installed, and I can create the custom post type or taxonomy, but I don't know how to populate that with the stores managed within the plugin.
Help!

Those are questions for the Agile Store Locator developers - and I'm pretty sure it's already storing the stores as a CPT and that they provide you with the ability to import stores using a spreadsheet/CSV file.
